# Why can't I load a site using Sharepoint Designer?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

When attempting to load the site I am working on through Sharepoint Designer 2013, this is what happens:

1. I type in the url "https://siteurl.sharepoint.com" and click open site.
2. A dialog box appears asking for username/password.
3. After entering username/password with edit permissions I click accept.
4. Error message: "Cannot connect you to site, please check your network and try again".
5. I click exit and the same dialog box reappears!
6. I exit again eventually the box goes away, I get: "https://siteurl.sharepoint.com/ The folder name is not a valid."

The site is hosted by Microsoft, if that matters. One time, once I exited the login multiple times, it seemed to actually be trying to connect, at which point I got the error "Cannot open non SharePoint sites". Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried opening the page in SharePoint Designer from the browser? Do you receive the same error?

Comment: Are you a site collection admin?  If not, whoever is could've setup a permission level to not let you use SPD.  The permission level `Browse Directories  -  Enumerate files and folders in a Web site using SharePoint Designer and Web DAV interfaces.` may not be active (this setting is on by default with edit permissions).

Comment: @SnWhte Yes I receive another cannot connect error. Thanks for responding!

Comment: @Jordan I can check and see but I would believe I would be getting an error that tells me I don't have permissions if that were the case correct? Thanks for the responses!